# ProcessBuilder.start() causes host JVM to exit

Tags: java, exec, processbuilder

I'm developing a networked application where there is a Client and Server JVM, both of which are supposed to depend on set of identical jars, which may or may not be stored in the same location. Immediately after connecting to the Server, the Client compares the MD5 Sums of its jars against the jars on the server.  If the MD5 Sums don't match, the Client downloads the Server's jars into a new folder and attempts to spawn a new `Process` that doesn't depend on any of the jars the Client is currently using, then exits.  This new `Process` is then supposed to overwrite the Client's jars with the copies from the server that the Client saved to the new folder mentioned abve, then exits.

The problem is, whenever the Client attempts to launch the new process, the Client's JVM exits silently.  Here's the code that spawns the new `Process`:

```
System.err.println("##### creating ProcessBuilder ...");
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder();

System.err.println("##### setting command line args ...");
pb.command("java","-jar","some-jar-not-used-by-the-client.jar");

System.err.print("##### starting ProcessBuilder: ");
for(String opt : pb.command()) System.err.print(opt+" ");
System.err.println();

pb.start();
System.err.println("##### Process started, exiting host process ...");
```

The Client appears to be exiting at the call to `pb.start()`.  Here is my program's console output:

```
##### creating ProcessBuilder
##### setting command line args
##### starting ProcessBuilder: java -jar some-jar-not-used-by-the-client.jar
```

The print statement after `pb.start()` never gets called.  I've tested this both in Java 6 and Java 7, and I've also tried using `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()`, to no avail.  Has anyone seen anything like this before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, this is a bug in Java 1.7.0_01 (running on 64-bit Windows 7 Enterprise Edition).  I updated to Java 1.7.0_02 and the problem went away.  I've submitted a bug report to Sun, here's the link to the report:

https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=7131522

It may take a day or two for the link to become active, but hopefully people with the same situation can follow the progress on this report and fix their issues accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't read your post but read [When Runtime.exec() won't - JavaWorld](http://www.google.se/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=when%20java%20exec%20wont&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCQQFjAA&url=http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html&ei=LRwXT-HSLeSL4gT5ktiPBA&usg=AFQjCNGqhuBvjTZ7yxzhCQJi7Dzlx9YivQ)

Comment: Yeah, I've read through that before - none of the cases in that article are remotely similar to what's happening here though.  My parent process isn't hanging or dumping stack traces, it's exiting immediately upon calling ProcessBuilder.start().  I'm also not using Runtime.getRuntime().exec() because the offically-preferred method of spawning processes in Java is by using the ProcessBuilder, per the Java API.  Good article though!

Answer (score 1):

Sadly the bug noted by Farmor has been closed

> State 11-Closed, Not Reproducible, bug
>   Priority: 4-Low

Comment: Yeah, I suspected they might do this.  I think they figure because you can get around the problem by updating Java to the latest version they just won't fix it in the older version.  Makes me a bit leery, because now I gotta tell all my customers not to use my software with Java 1.7.0_01...  oh well, you get what you pay for, I guess... :)